# ¿Como mostrar imagenes de instagram usando la api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram-api, instagram

Estoy intentando mostrar las imagenes de instagram en mi aplicación ruby on rails. El siguiente código funciona en mi maquina local pero en el servidor AWS no muestra las imagenes.

Al momento de hacer `file = HTTParty.get("http://www.instagram.com/legend_arnoldschwarzenegger/?__a=1")` no me trae los datos de la cuenta sino que me trae lo que pareciese ser el código web de la página, como esta [image: imagen] a diferencia de que en mi maquina local si me muestra los datos de la cuenta y se logran ver las imagenes que es algo como esto: `{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_31229027","show_suggested_profiles":false,"show_follow_dialog":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"Inquiries to email@gmail.com\nAll images are under artist copyrights","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":"http://www.website.com/","external_url_linkshimmed":"https://l.instagram.com/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wrl ...`, que podrá faltarme? Estoy usando las mismas versiones de las gemas. Este es el código de mi vista:

```
<%
require "open-uri"


  file = HTTParty.get("http://www.instagram.com/legend_arnoldschwarzenegger/?__a=1")

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que deberías usar para obtener resultado es con [`parsed_response`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/Response#parsed_response-instance_method).
De ahí puedes sacar las keys de respuesta y accederlas directamente, supongo que `graphql` es la que te interesa en particular.

```
2.6.0 :001 > file = HTTParty.get("http://www.instagram.com/legend_arnoldschwarzenegger/?__a=1")
2.6.0 :002 > file.parsed_response.keys
 => ["logging_page_id", "show_suggested_profiles", "show_follow_dialog", "graphql", "toast_content_on_load"] 
2.6.0 :003 > pp file['graphql']
{"user"=>
  {"biography"=>"FAN PAGE 
   "blocked_by_viewer"=>false,
   "country_block"=>false,
   "external_url"=>"http://Satisfiedbody.com/Conquer",
   "external_url_linkshimmed"=>
    "https://l.instagram.com/?u=http%3A%2F%2FSatisfiedbody.com%2FConquer&e=ATPjlqcIlHqYPH93cm1hwsMotC7zVjRV6Z0VErzUb39kv6i-dQu607awChiQAdrpnp9YIBGO",
   "edge_followed_by"=>{"count"=>20868},
   "followed_by_viewer"=>false,
   "edge_follow"=>{"count"=>3},
   "follows_viewer"=>false,
   "full_name"=>"Arnold Schwarzenegger Fan",
   "has_channel"=>false,
   "has_blocked_viewer"=>false,
   "highlight_reel_count"=>0,
   "has_requested_viewer"=>false,
   #...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder amigo @Alter te cuento hice lo que comentaste, en mi maquina local funciona tal cual pero en el server me manda el siguiente error supongo es porque igual esta trae el codigo de la pagina y no los datos del usuario: NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<String:0x00007f8f4f964e30>
from (pry):2:in `__pry__'

Comment: @LuisC prueba agregando un `format: :json` como 2do parámetro de .get